NATS horizontally scaling consumers
I have a bunch of subjects that are in the form of some_topic.<some_token>.

the some_topic part is always the same for all messages (it's fixed)
the some_token part may differ from a message to another, and I can't get an exhaustive list of all tokens as they may grow in real time

I want to make consumers that can easily scale horizontally (just running new consumer instances to handle more data), I also want the same consumer to handle all the data of a specific some_token . For example:

token A messages must always be handled by consumer 1
token B messages must always be handled by consumer 2
etc

One solution would be to read all messages in all consumers, extract the some_token part, apply consistent hashing to tell whether or not to process this message in the current consumer.
Also, I went through NATS docs and found that it's possible to have deterministic subject token partitionning, but from what I understand, I'll have to duplicate my stream (mirror) to achieve that.
So, I was wondering if NATS has something that could help me to achieve my goal without all of this overhead.
Thanks,
Ares
